# Prune yum of stale installed packages/duplicate gcc packages after manual install

Tags: linux, centos, yum, gcc

I'm in a weird situation, and maybe I've messed something up and just need to hit the reset button and re-install CentOS.

Off a fresh install of CentOS7.1 the other day, I noticed the latest version of gcc-g++ is `4.8.5-4`.  I'm working on a c++ project and wanted to try upgrading to a newer version.  I looked around and didn't find an easy way to install a newer one, so I found [gcc-5.3.1-2.fc24.x86_64](https://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=gcc-c%2B%2B) on rpmfind, started downloading this package and its dependencies, and went through installing the packages manually with `rpm -ivh --replacefiles` (not knowing I was probably screwing stuff up).

Once I finished, I updated a few things in eclipse and to my surprise, it worked.  I can now use the std-lib regex stuff in c++, it compiles my project, no weird issues, I thought all was well.

So I come back today to try and install teamviewer, which apparently requires `glibc.i686`.  I don't have it installed, and can't install it cause I'm met with some long text and: `Protected multilib versions: glibc-2.17-106.el7_2.1.i686 != glibc-2.22-6.fc23_x86_64`.  I then noticed when I check which packages I have installed, yum thinks I have`gcc-4.8.5-4.el7.x86_64` and `gcc-5.3.1-2.fc24.x86_64` both installed.

I'm pretty sure I don't have the 4.8.5 version any more, because I overwrote the files. Can I just remove 4.8.5-4, and install teamviewer/other 32-bit applications while keeping my gcc 5.3.1? Or have I really screwed up, and there's no way forward to run a clean environment while using a gcc version newer than the repo's latest?

Thanks

Comment: It might help if you would add the output of `yum check` and maybe also the list of the packages you installed, maybe via `rpm -qa --last | head -50`
As an additional help you could use `yum list all | grep '@'` which should show you all installed packages together with the repo they came from in the rigthmost column - you should be easily able to filter for those that are not from any normal CentOS repos ...